# Suggestions for Brie + Bread + Preserves

Tags: bread, cheese, jelly, brie

I've now tried two different types of Brie cheese from my grocery store.  The first was a triple cream version which was very mild and nice.  The second was a "Rich and Buttery" (whatever that is supposed to really mean) version which was just a little bit stronger.  I tended to like the first version more, at least in my preparation.

I ate both by spreading a thin layer of slightly toasted, light and airy bagguett and then topping with about half as much of either apricot or strawberry preserves.  I like both the preserves and the bread is nice, but I'm not sure what kind to try next.  There are double creams, store brands, international brands, etc...

**Does anyone have suggestions for:**

1. What types of Brie should I try?  Any specific terminology that will help tell the difference between the 10 or 15 types I see in the store?
2. What else to eat the Brie with?
3. What types of bread would be good?
4. Any other flavor of preserves that would be nice?

Comment: Questions calling for a list of answers should be marked community wiki. You'll see a checkbox for it when editing/creating your question.

Comment: Actually, I don't see a checkbox when I clicked the edit button.  Oh, did you mark it as a community wiki, already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrasting flavors and textures will bring out more excitement on the palate.

The rich buttery flavor of brie works well with crisp acidic fruit like apples,  or pears.  Consider salty items like various cured meats such as various types of ham, salami, sausage.  Smoke-flavored almonds and salty nuts (marcona almonds).

Other preserves:  Fig preserves & mango chutney

Breads:  Dark breads like pumpernickel, yeast breads containing dried fruit & nuts (especially when first toasted and then broiled to soften the brie and toppings of choice).

Comment: Apples sounds really good as does the mango chutney.  I'll have to carefully explore the salty/cured meat angle as I'm not a big salami/sausage fan, but I can tell you're onto something there!  Also, the idea for breads with fruits/nuts in them is another great idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's all about the [chutney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chutney)...Usually we're talking a spicy/fruity relish type thing. Excellent counterpoint to brie's regular smoothness, and comes in all flavors from sweet to spicy.

My personal favorite is [baked brie in puff pastry](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/party-starters/baked-brie-recipe/index.html). Talk about delicious. Serve it with fruit and sliced baguette.

As for types, the issue you're going to come up with is terminology. There are only two types of brie: Brie de Meaux and Brie de Melun. Meaux is the more common variety. Now brie-*style* cheese comes in vastly more varieties, and you're going to need to experiment to find ones you like best.

Comment: Wow!  The baked Brie in pastry sounds amazing.  I really like the chutney idea too.  Thanks for the explanation of the types of Brie too!

Comment: Get some decent English chutney or pickle (e.g. [Branston](https://bringoutthebranston.co.uk/please-the-cheese/brie/)) if you want it easy.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a common combination in Britain is brie and redcurrant jelly.

Comment: I love the uniqueness.  I'll have to try that.  We used to make currant jelly at home (Ohio) and I bet my mom still does.  I can imagine it now.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Brie de Meaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brie_de_Meaux) (aka King's cheese)
2. Try it with honey
3. French Baguettes
4. Fig preserve

Comment: +1 for honey!  I love honey and have only recently - in the last year or two - really started to love honey!